# Are Linux Headers installed by default? How to check if they're installed?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, kernel, lubuntu

- Are Linux [Headers](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders) installed by default?
- How to check - *via* command line - if they're installed?

**<sub>(in Ubuntu and Lubuntu 14.xx)</sub>**

Comment: IMO - Kernel headers are not required by default, unless its required to rebuild the kernel module or the kernel or for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linux headers are installed by default (See the [14.04 manifest file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) for example)

The [`linux-headers-generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-headers-generic) package will always depend on the latest generic kernel headers available.

To check the current version, open a Terminal and type:

```
$ dpkg-query -s linux-headers-generic
Package: linux-headers-generic
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 33
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux-meta
Version: 3.11.0.20.21
Depends: linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic
Description: Generic Linux kernel headers
 This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel headers
 available.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just open up the Software Center or Synaptic and make sure the package "linux-headers-generic" is installed.  That package is marked to depend on the headers for the latest available kernel version, so it will pull in another package or two for your particular kernel version.

Edit:
You can also just open a command line and run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

If it's already installed then it'll say so, and if not it'll ask you to verify you want to install the package.

Comment: don't like for two reasons: 1) using a `sudo` command when most probably can be avoided (after all, don't actually want to install anything) 2) "installing" only to check if installed may be effective but not elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of late, but I found this question with no interesting answer so here is the real way to do it so you know WITHOUT installing, which I think was what you wanted to begin with :

```
apt list linux-headers*
```

Output is going to be a linux-headers list with some with [installed] specified, such as this :

```
linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-amd64/kali-rolling,now 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-cloud-amd64/kali-rolling 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common-rt/kali-rolling 5.10.46-4kali1 all
linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-common/kali-rolling,now 5.10.46-4kali1 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.10.0-kali9-rt-amd64/kali-rolling 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64
linux-headers-amd64/kali-rolling,now 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-cloud-amd64/kali-rolling 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64
linux-headers-rt-amd64/kali-rolling 5.10.46-4kali1 amd64here
```